# How to create multisite blog with subdomains and shared content

Tags: content-management-system, subdomain

I'm looking for a CMS or a plugin (for any CMS) to create a multisite blog (using subdomains) with shared content, in the sense that from the HP of the blog "blog.com" you can reach the contents of "site1.blog.com", "site2.blog.com ", etc., that the categories of each blog and the authors are present in the HP menu and that all the contents of that category of each blog can be reached from the category pages of "blog.com".
Basically each subdomain must be autonomous, but the contents must be shared among all the blogs in the network.
It would also be useful to be able to suggest articles from other blogs in the network (eg articles suggested by "site1.blog.com" in "site2.blog.com").
What do you think is the best and fastest way to do it?
Alternatively, do you know if there is a way to retrieve blog.com/site1 content from the site1.blog.com URL without redirect?
Users should reach site1.blog.com[...] by clicking on articles starting with blog.com/site1/[...] and those who go directly to site1.blog.com/[...] should reach blog.com/site1/[...] (without URL changes).
I hope you can help me, I have searched but I have not found anything that could help me.

Thanks,
Michele

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: I tried the Wordpress multisite function, but apart from managing each subdomain as if it were a single site, it doesn't satisfy what I wrote. I haven't even found a suitable plugin for the purpose. Then I analyzed the MightySites plugin for Joomla, but even in this case it is not suitable for the purpose, I asked in the support forum and it was confirmed to me. Maybe something similar can be done with Drupal, but I'm not sure, plus I've never used it. Does anyone who knows Drupal know if it is possible? I looked for more information on the net, but I wasn't lucky.